# Redux-persist with immutable map not persisting state changes

Tags: state, immutability, redux-saga, redux-persist

I am using redux-persist with my entire state tree being stored as an immutable map as shown in my store.js file code below.

```
import {persistReducer, persistStore} from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import autoMergeLevel1 from 'redux-persist/lib/stateReconciler/autoMergeLevel1'
import { Record } from 'immutable';
import immutableTransform from 'redux-persist-transform-immutable';
const history = createHistory();
const middlewares = [thunk, sagaMiddleware, routeMiddleware, ReduxPromise];
// some imports omitted in the interest of brevity.
let persistor;

const MyRecord = Record({
    App : {},
    Auth : {},
    Box  : {},
    Calendar : {},
    Cards : {},
    Contacts : {},
    Course : {},
    DynamicChartComponent : {},
    Ecommerce : {},
    LanguageSwitcher : {},
    Mails : {},
    Notes : {},
    ThemeSwitcher : {},
    Todos : {},
    User : {},
    YoutubeSearch : {},
    githubSearch : {}
}, 'MyRecord')

const persistConfig = {
    transforms: [immutableTransform({records: [MyRecord]})],
    key: 'root',
    storage,
    stateReconciler: autoMergeLevel1
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, combineReducers({
    ...reducers,
    router: routerReducer
}));


const loggerMiddleware = createLogger({
    predicate: () => process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development',
});
middlewares.push(loggerMiddleware);

export default () => {
    let store = createStore(persistedReducer, compose(applyMiddleware(...middlewares), reduxReset()))
    sagaMiddleware.run(rootSaga);
    persistor = persistStore(store);
    return { store, history, persistor }
}

export function getPersistor() {
    return persistor;
}
```

My Problem is that even after I make changes to the state tree (which I have confirmed, do in fact take place as they should, using redux logger), the changes aren't shown in my application on refresh despite the fact that I call persistor.flush() like this:

```
export function* materialUpdate() {
    yield takeEvery(actions.COURSE_MAT_UPDATE, function*() {
        let secs = 2;
        while (secs > 0) {
            yield call(delay, 1000);
            secs--;
        }
        // const flushData = persistor => persistor.flush();
        // const persistor = yield call(getPersistor);
        yield put(getPersistor().flush);
    });
}
```

right after the state change (Also verified that that the flush action fires). I've tried everything and I would really appreciate any advice whatsoever, on the matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: ImmutableJS is a nightmare. Try [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) for peace of mind. You'd be amazed how bad ImmutableJs is compared to it